# Can't figure it out the underfull overfull from the error

Tags: overleaf

[image]

**I can't figure out why this problem occurs. Thanks in an advance.**

Comment: Those are not errors (hence the colors). These are markings of lines that are too long, for example with stuff that latex does not know how to hyphenate. You can add `\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}` in the preamble, then all of these are marked in the margins. Smaller values can often be ignored. Large ones need action. Often I'd wait until finished writing the text.

Comment: Thanks a lot @daleif for your valuable suggestion. I'm a beginner till now not understand all your direction you said. Not understand how to add \setlength\overfullrule{5pt} in the preamble.

Comment: Please do tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico. Sir, I use \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}  - class.

Comment: it is always better to show code and error messages as text in a code block `{}` button in the editor, orefably a small complete test document so people can debug it.  All we can say is that tex struggled to break the text into lines at good places but hard to suggest any improvements if only the image is available.

Comment: your `\iffalse` markup looks wrong though.  `percent \cite{C4}.\iffalse  \fi As a consequence` will typeset as "percent [zz].As a consequence" with no space after the sentence.